# Data length in ntext column?

Tags: sql-server

How do you find out the length/size of the data in an ntext column in SQL? - It's longer than 8000 bytes so I can't cast it to a varchar. Thanks.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Use [DataLength()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486(SQL.90).aspx)

```
SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE DataLength(NTextFieldName) > 0
```

Answer (score 20):

The clue's in the question: use `DATALENGTH()`. Note it has a different behaviour to `LEN()`:

```
SELECT LEN(CAST('Hello   ' AS NVARCHAR(MAX))), 
       DATALENGTH(CAST('Hello   ' AS NVARCHAR(MAX))), 
       DATALENGTH(CAST('Hello   ' AS NTEXT))
```

returns 5, 16, 16.

In other words, `DATALENGTH()` doesn't remove trailing spaces and returns the number of bytes, whereas `LEN()` trims the trailing spaces and returns the number of characters.

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Max(DataLength([NTextFieldName])) from YourTable
```